# Explain what this c++ bool line mean in this cpp book

Tags: c++, boolean, conditional-statements

```
playpen pp;
bool more(true);    
do{
   display_content();
   int const choice(get_choice));
   more = do_choice(pp, choice);
} while (more)
```

function code >>

```
bool do_choice(int choice){
bool more(true);
switch(choice){
case 0:
  clear_playpen(???);
  break;
case 1:
  more = false;
  break;
case 2:
  change_plotmode(???);
  break;
case 3:
  plot_pixel(???);
  break;
case 4:
  change_scale(???);
  break;
default:
    throw problem("Not a valid option");
 }
return more;
}
```

the `do_choice` function has a declaration `bool do_choice(int choice);`
with the last line in definition as `return true` to the `bool` type. Why will the author again in the cpp script above say `more = do_choice(...)` which I am understanding to mean `true = true // what use is that?` Sounds gibberish to me

Comment: You might be missing something - like another `return` statement. Add the code for `do_choice`,

Comment: Show the full `do_choice()`. Maybe it can return `false` earlier. No point in speculating without having it here to see. You should also clarify what you think `true = true` means, as that might not be what it really means; "Sounds gibberish" is not a great explanation. I vote to close due to incomplete code and an unclear question about it.

Comment: `=` is an assginment operator. `more = do_choice(...);` means that "overwrite the contents of `more` by what is returned from `do_choice`"

Comment: When the person writes `int i = 5;` and then `i = i + 1;` which I am understanding to mean `5 = 6` what use is that? Sounds gibberish to me.

Comment: @user253751 `=` is not declaring equivalence, it's a variable assignment

Comment: I assume the code in the book had `while` and `int`. `c++` is case sensitive meaning `Int` is different from `int`

Comment: If you think the function always returns `true`, you are clearly wrong, since it merely initialises `more` to `true` but then can change it to `false` in `case 1`, which will then fail the comparison and end the `while` loop.

Comment: thanks @underscore_d . I get it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the assignment operator (`=`) with the comparison operator (`==`).
The call to `do_choice` updates `more` so the loop will stop eventually.